# Eliminating common factor in display of MATLAB matrices

Tags: matlab

What I am trying to do is probably relatively simple.

[image: faulty matrix display]

As you see, this matrix is being displayed such that all terms are to be multiplied by 1.0e+04. I want to disable this feature and see the numbers as they "really" are.

Comment: Have you tried to set the [`format`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/format.html), e.g. `format shortG` or `format longG`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` command can fix this for you.  From the docs:

```
  FORMAT SHORT     Scaled fixed point format with 5 digits.
  FORMAT LONG      Scaled fixed point format with 15 digits for double
                   and 7 digits for single.
```

These are the defaults, and what you want is:

```
  FORMAT SHORTG    Best of fixed or floating point format with 5 
                   digits.
  FORMAT LONGG     Best of fixed or floating point format with 15 
                   digits for double and 7 digits for single.
```